# Disabled and need help answering HTC EVO shift with 2.2

Tags: auto-answer

I am a disabled guy in a wheelchair with an HTC EVO shift. I need help answering my phone without using my hands. My Motorola phones always had auto answering options but I need that for this super duper fancy expensive phone I just received. There must be more people out there that need the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

I thought this was totally possible but for the life of me can't find anything that says it is.  I was sure I had seen that option somewhere but going through the settings on my EVO 4G (similar to the Shift) I can't find anything that says auto answer.  Same thing when I searching around online.

**So it appears that there is no built-in way to set Auto-Answer**

*However*, there are a few apps in the market which claim to provide this functionality (this is by no means all of them, just three from the first page of results):

- [AutoAnswer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.everysoft.autoanswer)
- [NACM](https://market.android.com/details?id=pl.apps4android.nacm&feature=search_result)
- [Advanced Telephone](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lab1945.advphone&feature=search_result)

If you don't want to go the app route I also found these [Blue Ant Bluethooth Headsets](http://www.myblueant.com/products/headsets/v1/index.php) which supposedly allow you to answer the call by actually saying the word "answer".  This may be a better option than to always answering a call instead you can tell the headset when to answer or not.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This phone runs an operating system called Android, and many features can be added by using external applications.

There´s one app calld AutoAnswer, that is very complete and free.

Here is the info about it:
http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-everysoft-autoanswer-ApiA.aspx